# The complex conjugate of the character of an irreducible representation is the character of another irreducible representation

Tags: representation-theory

Here the group is finite and the base field is $\mathbb{C}$.

I googled this phrase but only saw some exercises on this problem. Any reference or hint would be helpful. I remember there is a way of going to dual space but didn't manage to redo that. I am also interested in seeing different proofs or different ways of understanding this. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This essentially works because complex conjugation is an automorphism of $\mathbb C$

Comment: @MarkBennet I think this is enlightening. But in what sense? For example $x^2$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$, but squaring entries in a character table (when entries are all real) might not result the same character table.

Comment: $x^2$ sends real numbers to non-negative real numbers, so can't be an automorphism (an isomorphism from $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$) in any sense or under any operation.Complex conjugation is a field automorphism of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @MarkBennet I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\rho \colon G \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$ is a representation of $G$ on the finite-dimensional vector space $V$, then there is a dual representation $\rho^* \colon G \to GL(V^*)$ defined by $\rho^*(g) = \rho(g^{-1})^*$. It is important here that the representation on $V^*$ involves both taking the dual operator and inverting the group element, so that we have
$$ \rho^*(g) \rho^*(h) = \rho(g^{-1})^* \rho(h^{-1})^* = (\rho(h^{-1}) \rho(g^{-1})^* = \rho((gh)^{-1})^* = \rho^*(gh).$$

Since the eigenvalues of a transpose operator are the same as the eigenvalues of the original, this means that the eigenvalues of $\rho^*(g)$ are the same as the eigenvalues of $\rho(g^{-1})$. Now,

- Each entry in the character table is a trace (sum of eigenvalues),
- Each eigenvalue in a group representation must be a root of unity.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks! The last piece is to show this is actually a character for an irreducible representation. That is because the inner product of itself goes to 1.